# Logged User Fixture Does Not Work (FastApi with Pytest)

Tags: python, fastapi, cookie-httponly

I am making an authenticated client that is a pytest fixture of my fastapi application,the code below shows an authenticated user,that should be able for example to create posts,update and delete them.But when I use it in my tests,it shows an 401 response error (that is returned when user is not logged)

```
@pytest.fixture()
def authenticated_user(client):
    user_data = {
        'email': 'julioooo@gmail.com',
        'password': '123',

    }
    res = client.post('/users/create', json={
        **user_data,
        'name': 'julin',
        'job': 'farmer',
    })

    user_id = res.json() # this returns the user id 
                         # to send a request to api to confirm user creation
    user_id = user_id['id']

    verify_user = client.post(f'/users/confirm-user/{user_id}').json()
    print(verify_user) #print the confirmation message (debugging process)

    log_user_res = client.post('/auth/login', json={
        **user_data
    }) # this returns in the header a httponly cookie...
       # response.set_cookie() method

    client.headers={**log_user_res.headers}
    return client
```

After some time trying to debug this fixture I thought,well,the headers actually DO HAVE the httponly cookie in it,so the problem is in another part of the code,maybe in the part that checks if the user is logged or not

```
def get_current_user(
    request: Request,
    db=Depends(connect)
):

    user_id = request.cookies.get('Authorization')
    user = User.objects(id=user_id).first()
    if not user:
        credentials_exception = HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail=f"Could not validate credentials or Not Logged or User Does Not Exist",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
        raise credentials_exception
    return user
```

And I couldn't find the problem,then I realized that this dependency of connect function actually returns a connection from the production db, not from the testing one,soo I created a new one that is :

```
def test_get_current_user(request: Request, db=Depends(test_connect)):
    load_dotenv()
    test_connection_url = os.getenv('test_connection_url')
    user_id = request.cookies.get('Authorization')
    client = MongoClient(test_connection_url)
    users = client['TestJC']['users']
    user = users.find_one({"_id": user_id})
    if not user:
        credentials_exception = HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail=f"Could not validate credentials or Not Logged or User Does Not Exist",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
        raise credentials_exception
    return user
```

PS: In the original function I use mongoengine to be more practical,in this one I use pymongo actually because the test_connect function that returns a pymongo connection instance,is used for tests,because it was the only way I found out to fix a bug that I had in my code that every time I deleted the test db after ending up the tests,it also deleted the production db (which is not cool), because `Users.objects().delete()` did not work and `users.drop()` did,I am using this way,but returning to the point....

PS2: If you have seen this question before I updated it,sorry for the bad question,I was very sleepy XD

I even overrided the get_current_user dependency to this test one trying to fix the problem

I even created a "headers version" of this authenticated user fixture where I only returned `client.headers` and in the request just put in the post method `headers={**authenticated_headers}`

BUT NOTHING SEEMS TO WORK,every single time is just 401..401...AND MORE 401
Thank you guys for your time here I appreciate A LOT :)

Comment: Your test is not actually testing your application, just that you've written some code in your test that does something. You should not use `Depends` in your test function either, as that is a FastAPI specific thing for the request cycle. Instead you probably want to override the `connect` dependency with a connection to the test database, then use `authenticated_user` as a parameter in your `test_...` functions to get the fixture sent into your test function for further testing (I'd rename it to `authenticated_client` instead, it represents a client, not an user)

Comment: Hi! (sorry for just replying now) ,I think I did not explained the code right,but thanks,I used your suggestion  of overriding the dependencies and with some more ajustments it worked !